# Is there a way to set custom data per cell in Godot 4?

Tags: tilemap, godot, godot-4, tilesets

My idea is to mark a cell as "occupied" when a character is in that cell doing something so no other character can be on that cell working.

My first thought was to set a `custom data layer` in the `TileSet` named "occupied" with a boolean value and change this value when somebody was in there, ie:

```
# mark as occupied
var tile_data: TileData = Station.get_cell_tile_data(Tiles.FLOOR_LAYER, closest_working_cell)
tile_data.set_custom_data(Tiles.OCCUPIED_LAYER, true)

# set occupied to false
var tile_data: TileData = Station.get_cell_tile_data(Tiles.FLOOR_LAYER, working_cell)
tile_data.set_custom_data(Tiles.OCCUPIED_LAYER, false)
```

But, after some unwanted behaviour of the characters, I've understood that this marks/unmarks **all** the cells in the FLOOR_LAYER as occupied, which I do not want.

I'm thinking of having an `Array[Vector2i]` of occupied cells and adding/removing them. Or maybe another "invisible" `TileMap` with just the occupied cells so I can check for them.

Or maybe I'm missing something and I'm overcomplicating this.

Comment: Since I've been mostly doing 3D, I'm not familiar with the details of `TileMap`, however... I believe you should be able to add and remove cells from the data layer. Barring that, a second `TileMap` was often the way in Godot 3. Barring that, consider using a dictionary with `Vector2i` as key (any value such as `true` would do), then you check if it has or not the key, effectively using it as a set.

Comment: For clarification on what's happening with your existing solution: `get_cell_tile_data` will not get the data _for_ an individual cell, but will get the data for the tile _used by_ that cell.  I assume your `FLOOR_LAYER` hasn't been painted with any tiles, which means all cells point to the same piece of `TileData`.  It's one level of indirection removed.

Comment: @Tanaki Yes, after some headaches I arrived to that conclusion. Hence the question ;) I thought that with `TileData` you could set custom data per cell, like occupied, oxygen level or whatever. And yes, the FLOOR_LAYER has cells painted, all the same, which is the floor tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by extending the TileMap class thus:

```
extends TileMap
class_name LevelMap

var grid = [] # for the 2d grid

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    var dimensions = get_used_rect().size
    for y in dimensions.y:
        grid.append([])
        for x in dimensions.x:
            grid[y].append(null)

func SetObjectInGrid(position, object):
    grid[position.y][position.x] = object
    
func GetObjectInGrid(position):
    return grid[position.y][position.x]
```

This creates a 2d array based on the dimensions of the TileMap.

I have a couple of functions to set the values at the given position (in this case I was storing an object at each location).

When trying to find the right position (global 2d coordinates) to pass in, I make use of the local_to_map function of Tilemap:

```
var tile_pos = LevelTileMap.local_to_map(position)
LevelTileMap.SetObjectInGrid(tile_pos, object)
```

Quick note on the [y][x] array format I use; I don't think this matters which way round you do it, this is just personal preference for me - I see it as an array of rows (which in turn are an array of columns).

Comment: For now, I went with the `Array[Vector2i]` of occupied cells which works nice with the `has()` method of the `Array` class. But in the future I'll have to store more than a simple bool in a cell, so I'll use your solution. Thanks.